# value of label is lost after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a aspx page which contains a update panel. Inside update panel I have a repeater. I am accessing labels inside repeater through jquery and assigning them values. But after assignment the value is lost. My asp.net aspx page is

```
<div class="row">
```

```
<div id="countdowntimer" class="text-center"><span id="timer"></span></div>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptMgr" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updpan" UpdateMode="Conditional">

<ContentTemplate>

<p class="text-right"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMarksText" Text="Marks : "></asp:Label>
                      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMarks" ></asp:Label>
</p>
<br /><br />
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuestions" runat="server" 
        onitemcommand="rptQuestions_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>

                <div class="panel divrpt" id="divhead" runat="server"><br />
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQno" Text='<%#Eval("Qno") %>'></asp:Label>
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestion" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>'></asp:Label>
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblqid" Text='<%# Eval("Qid") %>'></asp:Label>
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltotal" Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOnlyForJQueryQtype" Text='<%#Eval("Qtype")%>' />
               <p class="text-right"><asp:Label class="text-success" runat="server" ID="lblRight" Visible="false"></asp:Label></p> 
                <%--</div>
                <div class="panel" id="divbody" runat="server">--%>
            <div id="Div1" runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval("Qtype").ToString() == "1") %>'>


                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAnsDesc" Text="Answer :"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox id="textans" runat="server" Rows="2" Columns="40"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div id="Div2" runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval("Qtype").ToString() == "2") %>'>

                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAnsMulti1" Text=" 1:"></asp:Label>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk1" />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblch1" Text='<%# Eval("choice1") %>'></asp:Label><br />

                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAnsMulti2" Text=" 2:"></asp:Label>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk2" />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblch2" Text='<%# Eval("choice2") %>'></asp:Label><br />

                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAnsMulti3" Text=" 3:"></asp:Label>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk3" />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblch3" Text='<%# Eval("choice3") %>' ></asp:Label><br />

                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAnsMulti4" Text=" 4:"></asp:Label>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk4" />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblch4" Text='<%# Eval("choice4") %>' ></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div id="Div3" runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval("Qtype").ToString() == "3") %>'>

                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltf" Text="Choose True or False :"></asp:Label>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdtrue" Text=" True " GroupName="tf" />&nbsp&nbsp
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rdfalse" Text=" False " GroupName="tf"  />
           </div>
           <br />
            <asp:Button class="btn btn-default" runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Qtype")%>' />
            <hr />
            </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I assigned value to label using jquery. That code is as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.divrpt').find('[id*="lblqid"]').hide();
    $('.divrpt').find('[id*="lblOnlyForJQueryQtype"]').hide();
});
```

To bind controls inside update panel

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
    $('.divrpt').find('[id*="lblqid"]').hide();
    $('.divrpt').find('[id*="lblOnlyForJQueryQtype"]').hide();
    $('[id*="btnSubmit"]').on("click", function () {
        testAnswer();
    });
    $('[id*="btnNext"]').on("click", function () {
        $('[id*="imageResult"]').hide();
    });
});
```

and the ajax call for checking values

```
function testAnswer() {
var qtype, qid;
var record="";
var ansDesc = null;
var tf, ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4;
qid = $('.divrpt').find('[id*="lblqid"]').text();
qtype = $('.divrpt').find('[id*="lblOnlyForJQueryQtype"]').text();
record += qid;
record += "," + qtype;
if (qtype == 1) {
    ansDesc = $('.divrpt').find('[id*="textans"]').val();
    record += "," + ansDesc;
}
else if (qtype == 3) {
    tf = $('.divrpt').find('[id*="rdtrue"]').is(":checked");
    record += "," + tf;
}
else if (qtype == 2) {
    ch1 = $('.divrpt').find('[id*="chk1"]').prop("checked");
    ch2 = $('.divrpt').find('[id*="chk2"]').prop("checked");
    ch3 = $('.divrpt').find('[id*="chk3"]').prop("checked");
    ch4 = $('.divrpt').find('[id*="chk4"]').prop("checked");
    record += "," + ch1;
    record += "," + ch2;
    record += "," + ch3;
    record += "," + ch4;
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "StudentTest.aspx/answer",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ parameter1: record }),
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d == "correct") {
            var mks = $('[id$="lblMarks"]').text();
            var marks = ++mks;
            $('[id$="lblMarks"]').text(marks);
            alert($('[id$="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMarks"]').text());
            $('[id*="imageResult"]').show();
            $('[id*="imageResult"]').html('<p class="text-center"><img src="img/correctAnswer.png" height="50px" width="50px" class="img-circle"/></p>');
        }
        else {
            $('[id*="imageResult"]').show();
            $('[id*="imageResult"]').html('<p class="text-center"><img src="img/wrongAnswer.jpg" height="50px" width="50px" class="img-circle" /></p>');
        }
    }
});
```

}

the button click events are as below

```
$('[id*="btnSubmit"]').on("click", function () {
   testAnswer();
});
$('[id*="btnNext"]').on("click", function () {
    $('[id*="imageResult"]').hide();
    $('.divrpt').css("background", "white");
});
```

The label is assigned a value on success of ajax call but the value is lost.
I have no idea why this is happening. I have rebound the controls because of update panel.
How do we keep the value of label after updating it.

Comment: Does the page postbacks when you click on Submit button?

Comment: on submit button click the ajax call is made to server. The values are fetched correctly from ajax call and these values are assigned to label correctly. But after that when the control reaches inside prm.add_endRequest(function () { the values are lost

Comment: The values of a Label Control that are changed with jQuery do not persist across a PostBack if the Label control is inside the UpdatePanel.